# $-1$ is not a sum of square

Tags: galois-theory

Prove that $−1$ is not a sum of squares in the field $\mathbb{Q(\beta)}$ where $\beta = 2^{1/3}e^{2\pi i /3}$

My attempt : In fact $\Bbb Q(\beta)$ and $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$ are naturally isomorphic. So I need to show $−1$ is not a sum of squares in the field $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$.

Actually I can't find any way to do this after this point. Any help/hint in this regards would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean a sum of any number of squares?

Comment: Hint : if it was, it would also be a sum of squares in ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$

Comment: Well, what do you know about similar problems, what results have you seen that would allow you to draw the required conclusion, or what thoughts do you have in general? Come on, you can't just say that you have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know  any algebra. Lately I've been "self-teaching" myself a little, based on thinking about MSE questions. My point being this: It took me a few minutes to figure out the point to Ewan Delanoy's hint, while in fact it should have been immediately clear to someone who's been studying the subject, like from books and classes and things:

In fact $\Bbb Q(\beta)$ and $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$ are naturally isomorphic. This is just a special case of the following, which *must* be a basic result that's been covered in class:

> > Theorem. Suppose $F$ is a field, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic and have the same minimal polynomial $m$. Then $F(\alpha)$ and $F(\beta)$ are isomorphic (via $\alpha\mapsto\beta$).

Proof: They're both isomorphic to $F[x]/\langle m\rangle$.

Comment: Hehe..."don't know any algebra"...:) If not for the very nice answer, that already gets a +1 from me.

Comment: @DonAntonio No, seriously - if I knew some algebra the whole thing would have been obvious - that's probably the reason for the downvotes. Certainly would have been obvious given Ewan's hint. But in fact I had to start by working out the multiplication in $\Bbb Q(\beta)$, writing the elements as $a+b\beta+c\beta^2$. _Then_ I noticed that (i) the calculations would be exactly the same if $\beta$ were anything with $\beta^3=2$, and only then did I realize the "real reason" for (i), as above. So now I know a little more algebra than I did before...

Comment: I think someone that writes such a delicious book in complex analysis as you did (with covering groups, groups of Moebius transformations, etc.) must know a good deal of algebra. At least enough to fully understand the above. I though can understand it didn't "jump" to your mind when reading the question, but that's another matter.

Comment: @DonAntonio [blush] glad you liked it...

Comment: @DonAntonio: thanks for mentioning his book. Like abstract algebra, complex analysis is also one of my weaknesses. Will try to get hold of "Complex made simple".